# Make a question with processing multiple columns

Tags: sql, metabase

I need to make a calculations like: count of rows with filter divided by total count of rows. (`Count(filtered_rows) / Count(total_rows)`)

I can't find a good solution on how to make it in Metabase in a single question or somehow to make default filters work on dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do:

```
select avg(case when <filter condition> then 1.0 else 0 end)
```